# Install and use Protocol Buffers for Java on Windows

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

The documentation for using [Google Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) for Java in Windows environment is not very friendly, scattered and puts the new user into confusion. Here is a small attempt to assist the new explorers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Download the Win32 binary from https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases - At the time of writing, the latest is v3.3.0 and hence appropriate binary is https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.3.0/protoc-3.3.0-win32.zip
2. Extract this zip file into a directory and add the bin directory under this into the system path environment variable.
3. Checkout the source code from Github repository - As v3.3.0 is the latest release, checkout the same tag rather than master.
4. Copy protoc.exe from step 1 and paste it under src directory in the checked out location.
5. Continue to run maven tasks as provided here - https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/java

To run the [examples](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/examples) in the library -

1. Copy the `protoc.exe` from step 1 above to a preferred location and ensure that location is added into the `Path` environment variable. To ensure it is done properly, open a new command prompt and run `protoc --version` to see the appropriate version you installed.
2. Create the Java package for protocol format given with the examples - defined in `addressbook.proto` as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#compiling-your-protocol-buffers) - `protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto` - This generates the required `AddressBookProtos` class under the package `com.example.tutorial` which is required for compiling the example code.
3. Once the generated code is in the example classpath, the code can be executed.

Answer (score 3):

As a simpler approach, especially for occasional users, you could also just:

1. copy and paste your schema fragment here: https://protogen.marcgravell.com
2. select "(protoc) Java" (or whatever language you need), and click "generate"
3. copy out your code, or marvel at the in-editor errors and warnings in your schema fragment

Current limitations:

- only a single input and output document is available - this is purely a UI issue (I need to get a tabbed editor working, hopefully this week)
- which also means that "import" is heavily constrained - although a few inbuilt imports will work fine ("google/protobuf/duration.proto" for example, will resolve and work correctly)
- currently, if the "non protoc" parser detects a syntax error and your schema includes the word "import", it won't invoke "protoc" - this is while I investigate whether protoc could ever be abused to access unexpected files

Comment: That's a nice tool you've come up with. Will definitely help for most of the users as generating the stubs would be a rare activity. Not sure why, but it did not work for me when tried with Java and few other languages as well.

Comment: @PavanKumar huh, that's odd - I tried it on java (against some of my own things) before posting; does your schema involve "import" of non-default protos? if so: see the limitations above; I intend changing to a tabbed editor soon, which would enable multiple inputs and outputs, including "import". If it isn't the "import" limitation, I'd be very interesting in knowing what you *did* see

Comment: @PavanKumar oh, I see the problem - I can fix that - one sec...; update: the problem was that I wasn't checking sub-folders for generated files - I guess my own smoke test didn't have a package specified, so: no folders; fix is deploying currently - in a few moments this should work as a non-trivial example https://protogen.marcgravell.com/#gf906e3bfba5fe679f12b46ef54741563 (and [here's the fix commit](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/commit/e38b76bbf63f2c3e686627f035eb685ae3abea16))

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I pasted schema and selected Java. Clicking on 'Generate' button does nothing. I expect some output.

Comment: @Mandroid tested, working fine here, but it looks like maybe the error highlighting has broken for "protoc" - I'm guessing there's an error in the schema but it can't quite tell you what - I'll need to look. FWIW, when the schema has an error, with protoc selected, I'm getting `{"files":null,"parserExceptions":null,"exception":null}`, which is... ungood